# One line Destructuring of an object inside an array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Given an array:

```
const array = [{a:1}]
```

Is there a one liner to extract the value of `a` using `destructuring`?

I tried something like this which doesn't work:

```
const [{a} = array]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could unpack array and then first object inside it to get `a`.

```js
const array = [{a:1}]
const [{a}] = array;
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.
Is it possible to create the variable with a different name from the property?

So in your example I would  `console.log(not_a)` and see the value of `a`

Comment: You can assign different name like this https://jsfiddle.net/89sj03tx/1/

Answer (score 2):

```js
([{a}] = [{a:1}]);
console.log(a);
```

And in case if you need new name for the variable then do

```js
([{a: somevariable}] = [{a:1}]);
console.log(somevariable);
```